# How to close scanner class if we did not create reference variable for object so how to avoid resource leak warning message

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How to close scanner class if we did not create object for it to avoid warning messages stating `unassigned closable value, resource leak`?

As I need to get input only once from user, I did not create reference variable for object  `Scanner class`.

My declaration to get input

```
int num = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Comment: Not possible with your syntax. You must take a reference of it

Comment: Theoretically, as soon as there are no active references to the object, it should get destroyed since garbage collection in Java is automatic.

Comment: Note that if you are making a scanner from system.in, you probably don't want to close it.  It actually closes the standard input stream and you won't be able to read anymore input after closing it.

Comment: yes i seen it gc will do automatically and also if we did not used any variable or object it will remove and make space available for other object. i just tried to save memory so tried to ignore creating reference variable. thanks for your time bro i assume and got to know scanner class must have reference variable to close.

Comment: then why this warning message i am getting @puhlen

Comment: @RaviNarayanan because in general you want to close resources but this is a special, specific case where you might not.

Comment: ok bro...thanks much for clearing me out.

Answer (score 2):

> i did not created object for Scanner class

yes, you did: `new Scanner(System.in)`

In case, you are allowed to use try-with-resource:

```
try(Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in)){
  int num = sc.nextInt();
  /* TO DO */
}
```

OR, just use the .close():

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();
```

Comment: Yes i did sorry with new keyword yeah i m aware of that and i used to do how you declared but i am trying to use different way as i am using only once so inside try catch block also
my declaration showing same warning message

Comment: Only in this way only we need to declare and close when we are using scanner ,so i can't implement in this way in java..right?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use try/finally:

```
Scanner sc = null;
try
{
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
}
finally
{
    if(sc!=null)
    {
       sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roman these all i know bro, so this is the only  way we need to declare and close..my new declaration is not possible in java right...?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way with your syntax to close the `scanner` object.

Only one way I can think of right now is, if `Scanner` would not have been a `final` class, we could created a `class` which extends it says `ScannerAutoClose` and declare/override a `finalize` method for it and close the object in it using `this.close()`. The `finalize` 
 method would have been called at the time of garbage collection so it get's closed automatically. But since `Scanner` is `final class`, this is out of the picture.