# Does unreferenced Scanner object close automatically?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java.util.scanner

This question is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52050299/10701114) but none of them answered if it can be closed.

They only suggested alternatives- using `try-with` or actually having a reference like `Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in)`.

This led to me thinking that unreferenced Scanner objects can't be closed but...

Question: Shouldn't the objects become **eligible** for **garbage collection** and thus will be closed ultimately?
(Note: I do realise that depending on the GC isn't a great idea)

Comment: `Scanner` does not autoclose.  Note, closing `scanner` here would **also** close `System.in` (which is a global).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the OpenJDK source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java), `Scanner` doesn't override the `finalize` method. This means no special code is executed when the object is eventually collected, and you need to close it explicitly.

**EDIT:**
This is probably intentional, since a common usecase for `Scanner` is to use it on `System.in`, which you should never close.

Comment: In short, the object is garbage collected, but the underlying stream is still open?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, exactly

Comment: In general, objects wrapping another resource object will never have a finalizer closing them, as it is always possible that a wrapper gets garbage collected while the underlying resource is still in use, like in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488). So, the `Scanner` does not have a finalizer or cleaner, but the underlying resource, e.g. when wrapping a `FileInputStream`, may have. Still, this is not an invitation to rely on garbage collection of resources. The case of `System.in` [is special](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54822835/2711488)…